# Can Safety Goggles protect damage from Pokemon with the Solar Power Ability?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So, let's say that I have a Tropius Pokemon Omega Ruby with Solar Power, and make it hold Safety Goggles.

[Safety Goggles](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/In-battle_effect_item#Safety_Goggles) grants the holder immunity to weather-related damage and powder moves.

Meanwhile, [Solar Power](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Solar_Power_(Ability)), as said in Bulbapedia:

> During [harsh sunlight](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Harsh_sunlight), Solar Power increases the Pokémon's Special Attack by 1.5×, but the Pokémon loses 1/8 of its maximum HP at the end of each turn.

Harsh Sunlight can be created by the [Drought](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Drought_(Ability)) ability or using [Sunny Day](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sunny_Day_(move)).

My question is, ***can Safety Goggles protect damages that caused by Solar Power ability in Harsh Sunlight?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone asked a similar question on [another forum](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67867255) and the answer is no. Solar Power doesn't actually "do damage", the Pokémon just loses its HP. This damage comes from the ability itself and not the weather unlike sandstorm or hail damage, hence, no, the Safety Goggles don't prevent HP loss from Pokémon with Solar Power in harsh sunlight.